# Swingworker queue and single using

Tags: java, swing, executorservice, swingworker

I have 3 swingworkers. And 4 jButton.

jButton1 must assign for queued working of Swingworkers. When it clicked swingworker must be queued and executing one by one. We can use executor for it i know. I read many articles about it but people call executor from first swingworker done() method generally. I can't do it because;

jButton2, jButton3, jButton4 must assign to swingworkers for single executing. How can we create this scenario? Any sample schema appreciated.

Regards.

**---EDIT---**

MainGui looks like below ss;

[image: MainGui]

All my Swingworkers stored in other class;

```
package trying.project;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class WorkersClass {


    public class SW1 extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

         //Doing Some DB Jobs Here...

         return null; 
        } 
        public void done() {
         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }                      
   }   



    public class SW2 extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

     //Doing Some DB Jobs Here...

     return null; 
    } 
    public void done() {
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }                      
  }  



    public class SW3 extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

     //Doing Some DB Jobs Here...

     return null; 
    } 
    public void done() {
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }                      
  } 


}
```

All SW button must execute all swingworkers as ordered and one by one. SW1 first than SW2 than SW3.

SW 1 Button must execute only SW1,
SW 2 Button must execute only SW2,
SW 3 Button must execute only SW3.

Comment: Please write better english. Maybe you could also describe your problem a bit more or post some code

Comment: Sorry for my English. I use translator. I made some corrections in question. I don't have any code now. Just i write 3 swingworkers. I tested these are working and doing their jobs correctly.

Comment: I think posted here very similair code search for SwingWorker + Executor + 3-4 JButtons

Comment: But i dont find any useful sample. All my findings structured only for queued all SwingWorkers. And leap from one sw to another.

Comment: Question edited for more clarify...

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing for a while with this problem (if I've understood it correctly) and this is the simplest way I've found. I made 2 classes `WorkerManager` and `QueuableWorker` that work together to accomplish the following:

- No two QueuableWorker can be executed concurrently
- The workers must be executed in the order they were enqueued

The following test application has 3 buttons that create differents workers. No matter how fast you ask for executions the workers won't overlap and will be executed in order. The message in the console show when a worker is enqueued, started and finished.

To execute a queuableWorker call the method `queueExecution(worker)` of the WorkerManager, and override the `customDone` method of QueuableWorker to put you own code in the EDT after the execution.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class QueueSWTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new QueueSWTest();
            }
        });
    }

    static WorkerManager _workerManager;

    public QueueSWTest()
    {
        _workerManager = new WorkerManager();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Queue TestWorker 1");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String workerName = "Worker 1";
                appendMessage("Queued " + workerName);
                TestWorker worker = new TestWorker(workerName);
                _workerManager.queueExecution(worker);
            }
        });

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Queue TestWorker 2");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String workerName = "Worker 2";
                appendMessage("Queued " + workerName);
                TestWorker worker = new TestWorker(workerName);
                _workerManager.queueExecution(worker);
            }
        });

        JButton button3 = new JButton("Queue TestWorker 3");
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String workerName = "Worker 3";
                appendMessage("Queued " + workerName);
                TestWorker worker = new TestWorker(workerName);
                _workerManager.queueExecution(worker);
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(button1);
        buttonsPanel.add(button2);
        buttonsPanel.add(button3);
        frame.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        _textArea = new JTextArea("Queue some workers:\n");
        _textArea.setEditable(false);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(_textArea));

        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static WorkerManager getWorkerManager()
    {
        return _workerManager;
    }

    private abstract class QueuableWorker extends SwingWorker
    {
        @Override
        protected abstract Object doInBackground();

        @Override
        final protected void done()
        {
            customDone();
            QueueSWTest.getWorkerManager().setExecuting(false);
            QueueSWTest.getWorkerManager().executeNext();
        }

        protected abstract void customDone();
    }

    private class TestWorker extends QueuableWorker
    {
        public TestWorker(String name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground()
        {
            doHardWork();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void customDone()
        {
            String message = _name + " has finished!";
            appendMessage(message);
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return _name;
        }

        private void doHardWork()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String _name;

    }

    private static void appendMessage(String message)
    {
        _textArea.append(message + "\n");
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    class WorkerManager
    {
        volatile Queue<QueuableWorker> _workers;
        volatile boolean _executing;

        public WorkerManager()
        {
            _workers = new LinkedList<QueuableWorker>();
        }

        public synchronized void queueExecution(QueuableWorker worker)
        {
            _workers.add(worker);
            if (!_executing) executeNext();
        }

        public synchronized void executeNext()
        {
            SwingWorker worker = _workers.poll();
            if (worker != null) 
            {
                setExecuting(true);
                appendMessage("WorkerManager: Starting the next worker... (" + _workers.size() +" more queued)");
                worker.execute();
            }
        }

        public void setExecuting(boolean b)
        {
            _executing = b;
        }
    }

    private static JTextArea _textArea;
}
```

It looks like this:
[image: QueueSwingwokersTest]

Answer (score 0):

There are literally thousands of ways for accomplishing this task. Which one is the most appropriate probably depends on the context. And you did not tell us much about the context.

However, one simple way could be to create a list containing all SwingWorker instances that have to be executed. When the button is pressed, the list is processed (and the list here may either contain SW1, SW2, SW3 or [SW1,SW2,SW3] - or any other set of SwingWorker instances).

Processing the list means: The first SwingWorker is removed from the list. It will be executed, and when it is "done", then the remaining list will be processed. This can easily be accomplished by attaching a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker that gets notified when the SwingWorker completed its work.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class SwingWorkersExecution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        frame.getContentPane().add(createButton("SW1"));
        frame.getContentPane().add(createButton("SW2"));
        frame.getContentPane().add(createButton("SW3"));
        frame.getContentPane().add(createButton("SW1", "SW2", "SW3"));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JButton createButton(final String ... names)
    {
        String s = Arrays.toString(names);
        JButton button = new JButton(s);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                List<SwingWorker<?,?>> swingWorkers = 
                    new ArrayList<SwingWorker<?,?>>();
                for (String name : names)
                {
                    swingWorkers.add(new SW(name));
                }
                execute(swingWorkers);
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    private static void execute(final List<SwingWorker<?, ?>> swingWorkers)
    {
        if (swingWorkers.size() == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Executing first of "+swingWorkers);
        final SwingWorker<?,?> swingWorker = swingWorkers.remove(0);
        PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener = new PropertyChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)
            {
                if ("state".equals(event.getPropertyName()))
                {
                    if (SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE == event.getNewValue()) 
                    {
                        swingWorker.removePropertyChangeListener(this);
                        execute(swingWorkers);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        swingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
        swingWorker.execute();
    }


    public static class SW extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
    {
        private final String name;

        public SW(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println(name+" working");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println(name+" working DONE");
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void done()
        {
            System.out.println(name+" done");
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want:

```
package trying.project;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class WorkersClass {

    public static doSW1Stuff(){
        //Doing Some DB Jobs Here...
    }

    public static doSW2Stuff(){
        //Doing Some DB Jobs Here...
    }

    public static doSW3Stuff(){
        //Doing Some DB Jobs Here...
    }

    public class SW1 extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            doSW1Stuff();
        }
        public void done() {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }

    public class SW2 extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            doSW2Stuff();
        }
        public void done() {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }

    public class SW3 extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            doSW3Stuff();
        }
        public void done() {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }

    public class SWAll extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            doSW1Stuff();
            doSW2Stuff();
            doSW3Stuff();
        }
        public void done() {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also remove the SwingWorker definition and use [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) instead